# Why this event handling function is being called twice and updates the state twice in react?

Tags: reactjs

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
 
class TestState extends Component{ 

    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            count:1
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
    }
    handleClick(){
        console.log(this.state)
        this.setState (state=>{
          return  state.count++
        })
    }
    render(){
        return <div>
            <button onClick={this.handleClick} >Click</button>
            {this.state.count}
        </div>
    }
}
export default TestState
```

In the above code, when I click the button the counter increases by double value every time I click it ..  e.g.  On clicking the button the count will increase by 1, 3, 5, 7?
But state.count should only increase once because of the ++ operator.

Answer (score 1):

you should update the state like this

```
handleClick(){
    console.log(this.state)
    this.setState (state=>{
      return  { count: state.count + 1}
    })
}
```

because you return a object that you wish update not a integer

Comment: Because you mutate the state using `state.count++` but it's never should be used in react

Comment: Your answer helps so I upvote, but the question still stands, why state is being updated twice?

Comment: which version of react are you using?

Comment: I'm using react 16.x

Comment: I'm not 100% for sure about this but I think each time a state is changed then the view is rendered again. In the case happens two changes in state one when you use the  `state.count++` and other when you call set state the call is asynchronous then is possible they first increment and after call they execute the function setState calling  `state.count++` again

Answer (score 0):

The first answer is a solution, but the lifecycle method can be executed another way:

In my experience, ES6 fashion lends a DRY approach to updating state. Use of anonymous functions and implicit returns allow omission of the `return` keyword even though they aren't required if you don't rely on the value for another calculation ( Not recommended due to #setState's async nature ).

```js
handleClick() {
    console.log( this.state )
    this.setState( state => ({
      counter: state.count + 1
    }))
    
}
```

For more on the matter see: https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html

Comment: can you tell me why state is updated twice?

Comment: @CognnoxHR It can be a couple of things, **first** it can be because of the tricky nature of `post-incrementing` values in JS vs `pre-incrementing` so React is probably getting confused as it reads your operation as "set to original value then add 1". **Second** it can be due to your syntax in your original code, the way you wrote it is forcing React to 'merge' `state.count++` as opposed to `{count: state.count++}` that the built-in function is looking for.

Comment: Third, it can be due to the async nature of `setState` to begin with. Under the hood, React can and often makes multiple calls of this function for optimization reasons that to ensure its doing the job correctly, so coupling that with your incomplete syntax can lead to your issue. And **lastly* it could always be due to a parent component you tie your current component into. Even without seeing your file tree, I feel comfortable enough to assume that you're not doing anything of that nature given you are simulating a count effect. Does that answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

Mutating state directly, as you do in your example, can lead to odd behavior and is never advisable. Here is a quote from the [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate):

> NEVER mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may
> replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were
> immutable.

By doing this `state.count++` you throw React for a loop and as such see unexpected results.

I would rewrite your code like this: (https://codesandbox.io/s/red-lake-yk9gy?file=/src/App.js):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";

class TestState extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { count: 1 };
  }
  handleClick = count => {
    count++;
    this.setState({count});
  };
  render() {
    const { count } = this.state;
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.handleClick(count)}>Click</button>
        {count}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default TestState;
```